# Passing multiple request files to a method from the view?

Tags: django, forms, file, request, save

in Django when you pass form data to a form method, you usually call the method on itself changing the object from **form**.data['whateverdata'] in the view. to **self**.data['whateverdata'].  However when passing request files(2 in my case), Self doesn't seem to work neither does request.FILES['whateverdata'].  Any idea on how I might arrange this.

VIEW

```
def upload(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = VastTagForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponse("SUCCESS")
        else:
            return HttpResponse("form isn't valid")
```

Form method

```
def save(self):
    objs = VastTag.objects.create(media_impression=self.data['media_impression'],  
            media_file=self.FILES['media_file'], 
            companion_file=self.FILES['companion_file'])
```

Comment: once you have passed it through `is_valid()`, i guess `self.media_file` should work fine.

Comment: the form is valid. .media_file method doesn't exist unless you meant self.data['media_file'] but that doesn't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is best practice but it gets the job done. I made the save function take another argument and when the files are accessible in the view; I passed it to the save function.

VIEW

```
def upload(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = VastTagForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(request.FILES)
            return HttpResponse("SUCCESS")
        else:
            return HttpResponse("form isn't valid")
```

FORM METHOD

```
def save(self, files):
    objs = VastTag.objects.create(media_impression=self.data['media_impression'], 
            media_file=files['media_file'], 
            companion_file=files['companion_file'])
```